# scroll google map webpage sidebar using selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to collect data on a google map webpage, this is the link. [link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Amsterdamsche+Athleten+Club+Hercules/@52.36937,4.8049968,16.25z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x47c5e3c9cbb3d913:0xef85f93ef996cc06!8m2!3d52.3692292!4d4.8056684)

This is the code I have tried. My idea is to scroll to the "website name" (you can find the website name once you scroll down) once is present in the browser. but it is not scrolling.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/place/Amsterdamsche+Athleten+Club+Hercules/@52.36937,4.8049968,16.25z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x47c5e3c9cbb3d913:0xef85f93ef996cc06!8m2!3d52.3692292!4d4.8056684")

img_result = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[7]/div[5]/a/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",img_result)

print(img_result.text)

driver.close()
```

[image: check image]

what is the solution for this?

**EDIT:This is what I'm trying to get.**
[image]

Comment: What element are you trying to get there? Your XPath matching nothing there..

Comment: I'm trying to get this club, website name. with other links it worked. Can I get it with CSS_SELECTOR?

Comment: It's not about xpath vs css selectors. Almost all that you can do with one can be done with second. The issue is to create a clear, reliable locator. That's why I'm asking: what element are you trying to read?

Comment: I did an EDIT. That is the element I'm trying to read, How can I scroll there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on my side I see no need to scroll.
The following code worked:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Amsterdamsche+Athleten+Club+Hercules/@52.36937,4.8049968,16z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x47c5e3c9cbb3d913:0xef85f93ef996cc06!8m2!3d52.3692292!4d4.8056684"

driver.get(url)
name = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-item-id='authority']"))).text
print(name)
```

Output:

```
aachercules.nl
```

The same could be done with XPath instead of CSS Selectors.
This is the XPath I used:

```py
name = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-item-id='authority']"))).text
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked. Scrolling also worked, once I use the element.